# How i can sign and/or group a specific set of vertices in a 3D file container like OBJ ? - in Blender

Tags: 3d, blender, file, obj

I would like to export a 3D model with each part having a name or a label if you will.

For example i would like to export a model of an human body and name each part in specifics vertex groups like: left hand, right hand, right foot, head, ears, ... and you got the idea; so i can have a single 3D model that i can explode in various parts if needed.

If there is a better technique about how to mark vertex groups in a 3D file please share your solution. As 3D editor i use Blender.